# 'error: cannot find symbol' while displaying ArrayList using Comparator

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I made a class named `SortByFarz` and I tried to sort it in ascending order but  I am getting the following error and I don't know why:

```
  error: cannot find symbol

  Collections.sort(a1, new SortByFarz());
                           ^
  symbol:   class SortByFarz
  location: class Salaat
```

**CODE:**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Salat {

    private String name;
    private int farz;
    private int sunnah;

    public Salat(String name, int farz, int sunnah) {
        this.name = name;
        this.farz = farz;
        this.sunnah = sunnah;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setFarz(int farz) {
        this.farz = farz;
    }

    public int getFarz() {
        return farz;
    }

    public void setSunnah(int sunnah) {
        this.sunnah = sunnah;
    }

    public int getSunnah() {
        return sunnah;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s has %d Farz and %d Sunnah", getName(), getFarz(), getSunnah());
    }

}

class SortbyFarz implements Comparator < Salat > {

    public int compare(Salat first, Salat second) {
        return first.getFarz() - second.getFarz();
    }

}

public class Salaat {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Salat fajar = new Salat("Fajar", 2, 2);
        Salat zuhr = new Salat("Zuhr", 4, 6);
        Salat asar = new Salat("Asar", 4, 4);
        Salat maghrib = new Salat("Maghrib", 3, 2);
        Salat isha = new Salat("Isha", 4, 6);
    
        ArrayList < Salat > a1 = new ArrayList < > ();
        a1.add(fajar);
        a1.add(zuhr);
        a1.add(asar);
        a1.add(maghrib);
        a1.add(isha);
    
        System.out.println("UNSORTED SALATS");
    
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(a1.get(i));
        }
    
        Collections.sort(a1, new SortByFarz());   //Error in this line
    
    
        System.out.println("SORTED SALATS BY FARZ");
    
        for (int i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(a1.get(i));
    
    
        }
    }

}
```

Note that the classes are all in the same `Salaat.java` file.

Comment: Are these classes all located in the default package? In the same file or in separate files?

Comment: yes all of this is in the same file

Comment: Make your example SMALLER. Start removing all the fluff until you come to the really minimalistic code, which still have the same error message.

Comment: It's just a problem with the word, with a lowercase `b` of `by`. Possibly you're not that used to case differences if you're from an Arab country. In most PL's you'll see that everything is "case sensitive" making the identifiers completely different from each other.

Answer (score 5):

Check your spelling in `new SortByFarz()`. In your question you define the class `SortbyFarz`, notice the lowercase `b` in `by`.

If you see the error `cannot find symbol`, this means that you are referencing something that doesn't exist!